# How to access variable value declared inside main function to passing it to button_click method ? C#

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, user-controls

I want to access a variable value which is initialized inside main function on the button click. Please check my code first ...

```
{
    public string user { get; private set; }

    public Dashboard(String loggedinUser)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var user = loggedinUser;
        f1(user);
        // WORKING WELL WHEN I'M CALLING f1() FROM HERE.
    }

    private void f1(String usr)
    {
        Dock_MainPanel.Children.Clear();
        Passuc psuc = new Passuc(usr);
        Dock_MainPanel.Children.Add(psuc);
    }

    private void dash_nav_pw_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {     
        // USER VALUE DROPPING HERE. HENCE NULL VALUE IS PASSED TO FUNCTION       
        f1(user);
    }
```

I want to access **user** value which is stored in Dashboard function and to be passed next time when I am calling function **f1** inside dash_nav_pw_Click(). How to make it global variable and values should be static once assigned to **user** variable ?

Comment: Not really relevant for the answer but you may want to read MS Guide to naming conventions for C# as well - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change `var user = loggedinUser;` to just `user = loggedinUser;`

The first makes a new variable inside the function, the latter writes into the already existing outer variable.

Answer (score -1):

Since user is a public property in your class, it is already accessible.  Do not set it to local variable inside of Dashboard, just assign the value to the property.  You didn't provide information on how you want to use this value, but you can just get the value from the property directly.

```
{
    public string user { get; private set; }

    public Dashboard(String loggedinUser)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //set the value of the user property here
        user = loggedinUser;
        f1(user);        
    }

    private void f1(String usr)
    {
        Dock_MainPanel.Children.Clear();
        Passuc psuc = new Passuc(usr);
        Dock_MainPanel.Children.Add(psuc);
    }

    private void dash_nav_pw_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {     
          //Once the user property value was set by Dashboard, you can get it here
          f1(user);
    }
```